# Ajax, node.js, Express

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I see lots of posts related to node.js, ajax, and jquery yet I give a try to my question. What I have is that I am using jquery script to communicate with a server, the connection is established but no values have been found on the server side.

Here are the codes:

=========client side==============
function send(x) {

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "https://localhost:8080",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    data:JSON.stringify(laby)
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("ajax callback response:" + data);
});
```

}

=====================server side===============

```
app.post('/data',function (req, res) 
{
var store='';
for(var d in req.body){
    store=store+d+" "+req.body[d];
}
res.send(JSON.stringify(store));
 console.log(store);
});
```

=====================================

The ouput: "undefinde"

I do not know why this is happened and where the mistake is. Can anyone help?

Comment: The server side code is setting up a response at the '/data' url.  Your client side is requesting the root url.  Perhaps that is the issue.  Try changing the ajax request url to `https://localhost:8080/data`.

Comment: You mean at the '/data' url!

Comment: Also, **ALWAYS** check for errors. The server will tell you why it's not returning data, if you would only listen. ;)

Comment: On node.js side, can you check what's the output of console.log(store).

Comment: the output is still "undefined", I check it very times. I cannot store the values

Comment: If you're new to node, I'd suggest looking at [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org). It makes getting started easy.